# print issue in WPF .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8.1, desktop-application, .net-core-3.0

I created a sample `WPF` application in `.NET Core 3.0` with below printed code. It just works fine in `Windows 10` but not working in `Windows 8.1`. It is not giving any error either and hangs the application. Same code works in `.NET Framework` standard previous version without any issue even in Windows 8.1.

Please advise how to fix it in windows 8.1 .Net Core 3.0

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog printdialog = new PrintDialog();
    printdialog.PrintVisual(this, "My first print job");
}
```

Comment: Hello Sandy, could you tell us which Windows **SDK** you have installed in your development environment?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.I am using Visual Studio 2019 Community. Also tried vs 2019 professional but same issue.

Comment: @SebastianInones please let me know if you need additional details.

Comment: I just wanted to know which SDK (which is not you IDE) you have installed. Visual Studio 2019 comes with *Visual Studio 2019 SDK* but  you **may** be needing to install **Windows 8.1 SDK**. [Check it in here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive/)

Comment: ok @SebastianInones I installed Windows 8.1 SDK but no luck. Same issue I am getting. It works on the same win 8.1 machine if targetted framework is .net framework 4.6.

Comment: im getting this issue as well. Did you get a solution.